# Cant fetch data from sanity using next.js

Tags: next.js, fetch, sanity

I have my client.js file:

```
import { createClient } from '@sanity/client';
import imageUrlBuilder from '@sanity/image-url';

export const client = createClient({
    projectId: '********',
    dataset: 'production',
    apiVersion: '2023-09-08',
    useCdn: true,
    token: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SANITY_TOKEN
});

const builder = imageUrlBuilder(client);

export const urlFor = (source) => builder.image(source);
```

I have my schemas export in schemas in sanity:

```
import banner from "./banner";
import product from "./product";

export const schemaTypes = [banner, product];
```

I am trying to fetch data using getStaticProps in my page.js:

```
export async function getStaticProps() {
  const query = '*[_type == "product"]';
  const products = await client.fetch(query);

  const bannerQuery = '*[_type == "banner"]';
  const bannerData = await client.fetch(bannerQuery);

  return {
    props: { products, bannerData },
  };
};
```

But when i console.log(bannerData) i got undefined.

The error appears during getStaticProps, i have my banner and product data filled in sanity project manager